# Best way to auto-refresh an excel file on local drive and then update the graphs on Tableau Server?

Tags: csv, server, automation, tableau-api

I've literally searched everywhere on the web for a solution to this, and nothing seems to be working for me. I needed to query data from several databases, which was very complicated, so I decided to use Python to connect to the RDS's and perform these queries (via Pandas). Pandas exported this data into a csv file. Now I have the dashboard that uses this data on Tableau Server, but when I update the csv file, the dashboard doesn't update.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this. You can create a data extract and publish that extract to the server. This allows other users to connect to that data source for their own needs. Tableau server gives the user an option to schedule a refresh of the extract (as long as the server has access to where the data source is stored).

You could also just create the extract in your dashboard and republish. During the republishing, there's an option to set the refresh schedule there as well.

When you publish a workbook that references text file sources like csv or Excel, you have a choice to make about whether to include (package) the data with the workbook. The default is behavior is to include it. In that case, changes to the original csv file don't affect the published workbook.

You can try having the server reference the file by its path, but that can be brittle if permissions and Drive mappings are different on the server than your workstation. Better to publish and refresh an extract, possibly as a separate data source instead of packaged together with the workbook

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. When I created an extract and published to server, I get connection failure each time I refresh the extract

Comment: Your server needs to have access to the source file, like on a share drive, and not on your local machine.

Comment: I don't know if my company has a sharedrive. We have dropbox though.